# Removing code from a view still renders a jqGrid

Tags: ruby-on-rails, haml

I have zero experience in ror as of now, so there may be something really obvious that I may be missing. I am working on this project which is as such: app/views/index.haml has a tabbed menu, I select Menu 1, it's controller renders it's view in the center pane.

But there's a call at the end of app/view/menu1/index.haml to reder :grid_index.

_grid_index.haml starts with jqGrid which results in a table being rendered. I don't need that table - so I have deleted Everything from _grid_index.haml.

But still when I refresh in the browser, the table shows. I have tried restarting the server, the table won't go away. And Yes, I *have* saved the file.

This is where the code where jq Grid is rendered:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function gridReload(){
    var name = $("#name").val();
    var description = $("#description").val();

    $("#financial_reports_grid").setGridParam({url:"grid_data/financial_reports/index?name="+name+"&description="+description,page:1}).trigger("reloadGrid");
  }
</script>

<%= jqgrid("", "financial_reports_grid", "grid_data/financial_reports/index",
    [
        { :field => "id",                         :label => "ID",           :hidden => true },
        { :field => "financial_report_type",      :label => "Report Format",:width => "100" },
    { :field => "name",                       :label => "Report Name",  :width => "200" },
    { :field => "description",                :label => "Description",  :width => "400" },
    { :field => "show_financial_report_link",  :label => "View",          :width => "50", :align => "center" }
    ],
    { :ondblClickRow => "function(id){dblClickRow('financial_reports','show',id);}", :height => 350, :rownumWidth => 50, :gridview => true, :rowList => "[50,100,250]", :rowNum => 50, :viewsortcols => false, :rownumbers => false, :rows_per_page => 50, :add => false, :edit => false, :search => false, :error_handler => "afterSubmit", :direct_selection => false}.merge(grid_width_parameters)
) %>
```

Comment: Show use the partial/code where the jqGrid is rendered, and what, exactly, you're removing. Problem solving without specifics is little more than a theory.

Answer (score 0):

though I still don't know the answer to my question, but I did something else that sort of fixed the problem. I removed the call to

```
= render 'grid_index'
```

and that settled it. I am still interested in knowing where was that table coming from even when the haml file was empty.

Comment: Okay I found the reason. The reason was that I had made a backup of the original grid-index.ebu file and renamed it as grid_index_ebu.bu - and somehow the system was going for that file. Anyway, thanks for the replies.